# 2 queries return different results when I expect the same results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two SQL queries which return different results when I expect them to be the same.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(a.Id) 
FROM Accounts as a 
WHERE a.STATUS = 1 AND a.Type = 'A'
// returns 3529 results
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(a.Id) 
FROM Accounts as a 
INNER JOIN Payments as p ON a.Id = p.AccountId 
WHERE a.STATUS = 1 AND a.Type = 'A' AND p.STATUS = 1
// returns 3530 results
```

This is a conflict for our system. To retrieve unknown `Id`, which causes a conflict I have the query below.

```
SELECT t1.Id 
FROM (SELECT a.Id 
      FROM Accounts as a 
      INNER JOIN Payments as p ON a.Id = p.AccountId 
      WHERE a.STATUS = 1 AND a.Type = 'A' AND p.STATUS = 1) AS t1
WHERE t1.Id NOT IN (SELECT a.Id 
                    FROM Accounts as a 
                    WHERE a.STATUS = 1 AND a.Type = 'A')
```

This query returns no result and I'm unsure how to solve this problem.

A solved the problem thanks for your concern.

Comment: on your second query, group by a.id and display a count having count(*)>1. This should give you the exact record

Comment: So you you two rows in `Payments` with the same `AccountId`. Is that possible? If that should not be allowed you could add a unique index on `AccountId` after you've identified and deleted that intruder. You could also modify your query: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id) `

Comment: I used my own way to solve it by moving codes from one point to another point(syntax changes) for many times and its worked unexpectedly on one try. Hope it will not make me have troulble for following days. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Id,count(*)
FROM Accounts as a
INNER JOIN Payments as p ON a.Id = p.AccountId
WHERE a.STATUS = 1
AND a.Type = 'A'
AND p.STATUS = 1
group by a.Id
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an Account having a Payment with p.STATUS <> 1

Answer (score 0):

The inconsistency comes from the fact that one account can have *multiple* payments. For instance, in the `Payments`, there will be records like:

```
{AccountId=1, STATUS = 1}
{AccountId=2, STATUS = 1}
{AccountId=2, STATUS = 1}
```

So if you conduct `INNER JOIN` here, `SELECT COUNT(a.Id)` will count `AccountId=2`, twice. But in **Query 1**, it does not happen. That's why two results are different.